# Конвертация из RTF в TXT

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в WinAPI или в стандартных библиотеках Delphi функции для конвертации из RTF в TXT. Что-то типа: на входе TStream c RTF а на выходе String или PChar.

Вариант в runtime создавать TRichEdit прошу не предлагать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нету ни в WinAPI, ни в стандартных библиотеках Delphi. 
Не создавайте проблем - используйте TRichEdit или [**TRichView**](http://trichview.ru/). 
Если не желаете их использовайть - пишите парсер RTF. Материал о структуре RTF:
[**Wikipedia**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)
[**Автор RTF**](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10725)
[**Разбор**](http://libray.narod.ru/delphi/rtf_format.html)
[**Вот пример**](http://www.cyberguru.ru/delphi-sources/files-folders/preobrazovanie-rtf-v-html.html) того как человек извращался, конвертирую RTF в HTML(SGML).

Comment: Печально. RTF один из базовых форматов для Clipboard, и абсолютно непонятно почему в WinAPI не учтена конвертация в обычный текст.

Comment: А вот через буфер обмена можно и попробовать...<br>
Хотя нет - не получится, в буфер надо самому записывать данные в виде как и RTF, так и текст, и только тогда буфер будет знать что, то  что в нем как RTF это вот так, а  как текст это вот так.

Comment: Да, в буфер пишутся сразу несколько форматов